# How to fixate the camera on the player, so when the player moves the camera will follow

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, lwjgl

I am trying to make a OpenGL game in java in which you are a spaceship and you fly around in 3D space, the aim is to eliminate all of the enemy spaceships in the level. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to make the camera fixate/follow the player. I want to do this so that i can move the player (AKA: spacehip) around using user input and the camera will follow so that the player doesn't go out of sight (off the screen).

NOTE: I'm using modern OpenGL. (Shaders ...), not the fixed function pipeline.

Comment: If you can point the camera at an arbitrary location, then you can simply make that arbitrary location be "the player".

Comment: I have tried to say: cameraPos = playersPos. However this still seems to allow the player to wonder off screen. (Every game update).

Comment: But camera stays still or moves but player slowly recedes from it? Print both positions and check their values. Without some code we can only foretell.

Comment: The player just moves normally, however the camera's position is exactly the same as the player's position. Could it has something to do when the matrix multiplication in the vertex shader?

Comment: Does the player have a transformation matrix or are you just using vector + rotation angle etc?

Comment: The player (and all other entities) have their own transformation matrix which i multiply by the projection matrix and the view matrix (the camera's transformation matrix). These three matrices multiplied together and multiplied by the current vertex should give the final vertex position.

Comment: gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * transformationMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

Comment: My aim for the player movement is showed in this video that i found: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NrAnsbpOYI

Comment: Are you sure that the viewMatrix is calculated correctly(inversely) to the shipmatrix?

Answer (score 2):

(i'll explain in general code, not Java, but the syntax is easy to translate)
Assuming you're using transformation with Matrix 
all the objects in the scene are rendered By:

```
B * M * P,
```

while:

```
B = Base (or View/Camera) matrix
M = Model (or objects, like the enemies or the player spaceship) matrix
P = Projection matrix
```

in the Update cycle, which comes before the rendering cycle, right after you update the player's spaceship Model matrix, change the Base matrix accordingly, for example to put the camera behind the spaceship first find the heading vector of the spaceship and the up vector of the spaceship :

```
Vector3 vHeading = shipMatrix * Vector3(0.0,0.0,1.0);
Vector3 vShipUp = shipMatrix * Vector3(0.0,1.0,0.0);
```

then create the camera matrix placed behind the spaceship and looking at the spaceship using a LookAt calculations:

```
/// set the offsets between the camera and the spaceship            ///
float distCameraToShip = 2.0;
float cameraElevation = 2.0;
// find the ship position                                            ///
Vector3 vShipTranslation = shipMatrix.GetTranslation();
/// or Vector3 vShipTranslation = shipMatrix * Vector3(0.0,0.0,0.0); ///

/// calculate the camera transformation                              ///
Vector3 vCameraPos = vShipTranslation - vHeading * distCameraToShip + vShipUp * cameraElevation;

Matrix4x4 cameraMatrix = LookAt(vCameraPos, vShipTranslation, vShipUp);
```

a LookAt Implementation:

```
CMatrix4x4 LookAt(Vector3 vEye, Vector3 vObject, Vector3 vUp)
{
Vector3 n = normalize(vEye - vObject);
        Vector3 u = cross(vUp , n);
        Vector3 v = cross(n , u);

        float m[16] = { u[0], v[0], n[0], 0.0f,
            u[1], v[1], n[1], 0.0f,
            u[2], v[2], n[2], 0.0f,
            (u * -1.0 * vEye) ,
            (v * -1.0 * vEye) ,
            (n * -1.0 * vEye),
            1.0f };

return m;
}
```

you use this camera matrix for all the rendering cycle and pass it to the shader ex:

```
////// Vertex shader ///

/// it is recommended to do the multiplication on the CPU and pass the ModelViewMatrix to the shader, here is just to example ///
uniform mat4 u_BaseMatrix;
uniform mat4 u_ModelMatrix;
uniform mat4 u_ProjectionMatrix;

in vec3 a_VerAttrib;

void main()
{
gl_Position = u_ProjectionMatrix * u_BaseMatrix * u_ModelMatrix * vec4(a_VertAttrib, 1.0);
}
```

now you can start manipulating the camera and give it all kinds of cool interpolations, like set the distance between the camera and the ship according to the ship's speed :

```
float distCameraToShip = 2.0 + pow(shipSpeed,2.0) * 0.1;
```

you can also use time smooth filter to give it a cool following effect:

```
/// dt = time diff between updating cycles, or 1/FrameRate ///
float ct = 1.0 / (1.0 + dt);
cameraMatrix = cameraMatrix + (previousCameraMatrix - cameraMatrix) * ct;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the camera fixed of the player you will need to specify what what yaw and pitch (rotations) you would like applied to the camera and a distance away from the player then you would computer they distances to translate the camera so that you see the player from that angle.

Here is a brilliant tutorial on exactly what you are asking:
https://youtu.be/PoxDDZmctnU